# How do I check the web application running on a specific port?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I have a Ruby application running on a server.

When I run the `rails server` command on my server, it shows the following message:

```
Rails 3.2.13 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

If it was the local machine, I would have typed the following in my browser URL box:

```
localhost:3000
```

or simply:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000
```

Since this is the server, how do I do this?

I tried the following, but did not work:

```
http://IP_ADDRESS_OF_SERVER:3000
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You shouldn't be running a rails server in development mode. Use `RAILS_ENV=production rails server` Why are you deploying this way, by just starting a ruby application server? Will it be a really low traffic app?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `netstat -na | grep "LISTEN"` and this will show all active `listening` ports. The web application must be running on any of these ports.

You just have to try all of them to find it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the port is closed for outside connections.
Login on your server per ssh and run

```
$ curl http://localhost:3000
```

If it returns the rendered index page, the server is running but the port is just disabled by the firewall